# Limiting the touch area in the navigation barbutton item?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In iphone i  have known that the navigationbarbutton touch has also some extension under the navigation bar.But i need to limit the userinteraction to only a certain limit.Can i able to do that.Can anybody help me ?

Comment: A Quick idea: Use can put transparent `UIView` so that you can not touch that part !

Comment: @maulik i Have a button just under the nagation bar.so when i touch that button sometimes navigation bar button getting called...

Comment: Then I guess you have to change button position

Comment: but unfortunately i am having a like design.which has two buttons inside a view just under the navigation bar

Comment: If you are see some standard iOS application you will find the same behavior for the navigation bar button . I had same issue previously but I have failed to solve the this  .

Answer (score 0):

Implement a tap gesture recognizer and set your controller as delegate. Then implement:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

   // [touch locationInView] -> gives the point where the user touched
   // If the touch point belongs to your frame then return YES
   // else return NO

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom navigation bar yourself with hidden navigation bar "engine" behind and have the buttons on the custom navbar with the required custom behavior/visuals.
This also can be useful if you want to implement gesture logic (pan) to switch navigation pages.

AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
YourMainViewController *yourmainViewController = [[YourMainViewController alloc] init];
_navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] yourmainViewController];
[_navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
[self.window setRootViewController:_navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

YourMainViewController.m:  implement your view with custom navigation image and added buttons for navigation either using Interface Builder or programatically. For example programatically create your view:

```
- (void)loadView {  
...
    UIImageView *tmp_mynavbar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomNavBG.png"]];
    tmp_mynavbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
    [self.view addSubview:tmp_mynavbar];
    UIButton *tmp_addbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    tmp_addbutton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 10, 40, 20);
    [tmp_addbutton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tmp_addbutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomNavAddBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tmp_addbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedbuttonAddItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:tmp_addbutton];

// create button with the required size, user interaction area (add image then add transparent button with different size, etc)
// also add a back button
...
}
```

then implement custom navigation button behavior (the add/next button and also the back button)

```
-(void) pressedbuttonAddItem:(id) sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [[app navigationController] detailViewController animated:YES];
}

-(void) pressedbuttonBack:(id) sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```